# Technologies in or Technologies for

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct form for a company name:
 1. Digital technologies for logistics LLC
 2. Digital technologies in logistics LLC
 3. Logistics digital technologies LLC?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is going to be a matter of opinion, so I'm afraid I have to vote to close your question. Company names can be anything you like (see, for example, "Toys R Us", although that may not be the best example these days! Or L3.). For what it's worth, I'd go with option 3 because it is shortest, but that's an opinion.

Comment: Since company names don't have to obey grammar rules - any of the above. Which is best is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While indeed company names don't *have* to obey grammar ("Toys R Us", as Pam notes), questioner is asking how best to do so regarding these prepositions, and we should oblige. Technologies "in" implies tech *within* a field or category, as in this case "digital technology" (presumably microchip-implanted equipment from GPS to phones to computers). Technologies "for" implies tech used *for* a given purpose, as in this case "logistics technology" (presumably for example helping truckers deliver their cargoes efficiently and helping their employers track them). "Technologies *in* Digital *for* Logistics" sounds unwieldy; "Digital Techologies for Logistics" somewhat better; "Digital Logistics Techologies" the most compact of all. (Parsed as "Digital... Logistics-Technologies", the purpose being central, the type being peripheral.)